# Using PHP Foreach with 3 Arrays

Tags: php, foreach

I'm getting data from a site as you can see in the code below. Is it possible to use 3 arrays in a single foreach loop?

I've tried too many code snippets, but I haven't found the solution.

This is my normal code:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$url = file_get_contents("xxx");

$display = '#{"__typename":"GraphImage","id":"(.*?)","edge_media_to_caption":{"edges":\[{"node":{"text":"(.*?)"}}]},"shortcode":"(.*?)","edge_media_to_comment":{"count":(.*?)},"comments_disabled":(.*?),"taken_at_timestamp":(.*?),"dimensions":{"height":(.*?),"width":(.*?)},"display_url":"(.*?)","edge_liked_by":{"count":(.*?)},"edge_media_preview_like":{"count":(.*?)},"location":(.*?),"gating_info":(.*?),"media_preview":"(.*?)","owner":{"id":"(.*?)","username":"(.*?)"}#i';

preg_match_all($display, $url, $dop);

foreach ($dop[1] as $displayop1) {
    echo $displayop1."<p>";
}

foreach ($dop[9] as $displayop2) {
    echo $displayop2."<p>";
}

foreach ($dop[15] as $displayop3) {
    $i++;
    if($i == 2) {break;}
    echo $displayop3."<p>";
}
```

I've tried.

```
<?php

foreach ($dop[1] as $displayop1) {
    foreach ($dop[9] as $displayop2) {
        foreach ($dop[15] as $displayop3) {
            echo $displayop1 . "<p>";

            echo $displayop2 . "<p>";

            $i++;
            if ($i == 2) {
                break;
            }
            echo $displayop3 . "<p>";
        }
    }
}

?>

<?php
foreach (array_combine($dop[1], $dop[9], $dop[15]) as $dop1 => $dop2 => $dop3) {
    echo $dop1.$dop2.$dop3;
}
?>
```

These codes didn't work.

Can someone help me do this? I searched the solution a lot, but I couldn't find any information. I didn't know exactly how to search on the internet because my English isn't very good, thank you.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @Nik What I want is to use one loop instead of using 3 loop.

Comment: if the arrays have the same length you can use `for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {}` loop and print the items of the arrays like `echo $dop[1][$i];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closest option I see to a single loop is 2:

```
    for($i=1; $i < 15; $i++) {
    //you can do a if statement here if you need 1 9 and 15 respectivley 
    foreach ($dop[$i] as $displayop) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Was it really that easy? Thank you so much.. worked fine with if.. (Clap Clap Clap)